# Fetch Image without URL in Android

Tags: android, api

I'm developing an app and one of the components involves the user recording where they have gone for the day. I use some NLP to identify the location, however it would be awesome if I could also after obtaining the location or any other string for that matter get an image from an external API. I've seen people use image urls to get images for their android app but, how can I get an image without a URL, kind of of like a google images search? If this isn't possible is there a way to get an image url?

Comment: Google places API has images that you can get via location I'm pretty sure

Comment: You can try Unsplash SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Images Api:
https://serpapi.com/images-results